# javascript debug function using eval

Tags: javascript, closures

In C++ we can write a preprocessor macro like this:

```
#define DEBUG(x) cout << '>' << #x << ':' << x << endl;
int a=1;
DEBUG(a) //prints "a:1"
```

I tried to do a similar thing in javascript

```
var DEBUG= function(name){
  return function() {
      console.log(name+": ",eval(name))
  }
}
{
    let a=1;
    DEBUG('a')() //a is undefined
}
```

I was wondering if there was any way to "inline" functions or otherwise do some clever thing with closures which allows DEBUG to be evaluated in the calling scope. I know I could just call DEBUG('a',a) but that wouldn't be as fun ;)

Comment: `but that wouldn't be as fun` - but it's the only way

Comment: To summarize tadman’s answer: `console.log({ a })`

Comment: All you could do is `eval(debug('a'))`, where `eval` is called in the scope where the variable is available. Or you just do the same thing as in C++ and use an actual *preprocessor* which does macro expansion

Comment: @Bergi having debug return an eval string is pretty clever, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no need for such a heavy-handed approach. You can always do this:

```
function debug(a) {
  console.log(a);
}
```

Or you can define an empty version of same with no functionality to disable it in certain run modes.

To use it is easy:

```
debug({ a: a, b: b });
```

With ES6 you can do this even more concisely:

```
debug({ a, b });
```

Couldn't be easier.

Your idea of using `eval` is going to fail because `a` is a variable that only exists inside of that specific scope due to the `let` declaration. That means the other function has no ability to access it.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!